# How to manipulate an array value at java android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, spinner

i have an array from SQLite return value to passing at Spinner

At `DatabaseHelper.java` i create 1 void

```
public List<String> getSpinnerSupir(){
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + "sopir";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                labels.add(cursor.getString(0)+cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning lables
        return labels;
    }
```

I consume the labels value to display at Spinner

```
List<String> lables = db.getSpinnerSupir();
Log.d("array:", String.valueOf(lables));
```

And at Log display

```
[1Juniarto, 2Agus Haryanto, 3Supriadi, 4Cahyanto]
```

I need to manipulate to

```
[Juniarto, Agus Haryanto, Supriadi, Cahyanto]
```

How to manipulate it?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: If you're trying to remove the numbers, simply use a regex.

Comment: Why you dont pick only what you need with your query? I guess that the numers are the primary keys, so just select the names.

Comment: labels.add(cursor.getString(0)+cursor.getString(1));   u are getting two columns here  u need to change it to labels.add(cursor.getString(1));

Answer (score 2):

You are adding two columns `column 0` and `column 1` into `labels`

> labels.add(cursor.getString(0)+cursor.getString(1));

So u have IDs as column 0  so its getting added along with the string

Modify it to

> labels.add(cursor.getString(1));

**Edit**

returning both id and name

create a class like below

```
class Data {
   private String id;
   private String label;
   public Data(String id,String label){
       this.id=id;
       this.label=label;
   }
}
```

insert data into class

```
ArrayList<Data> arrayList=new ArrayList<Data>();
arrayList.add(new Data(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1)));
```

return the array list and use it :)

Comment: the getString(1) needed to display name, and getString(0) needed to get id, at the spinner will display of the name, and if the spinner on selected return the value = id

Comment: instead of adding data to labels   return cursor and  get the data near spinner and assign the values you need to spinner

or use a hashmap<String,String> with id and name   this hashmap can help you

Answer (score 0):

You are adding values from both columns `column 0` and `column 1`. If you need values only from `column 1` don't add `column 0` values

Change your code to add items as follows

```
labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want only the second column from each record. When calling:
`labels.add(cursor.getString(0)+cursor.getString(1));`
you get the numbers that you don't want. 
Instead, replace with `labels.add(cursor.getString(1));`

Comment: Looks like Haryanto is not alone. There is no comma in between 2Agus and Haryanto. They are together.

Comment: Missed that, than you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use column name while getting the value from cursor in your *getSpinnerSupir* method.

Instead of below line;

> labels.add(cursor.getString(0)+cursor.getString(1));

Use something like;

```
labels.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("your_column_name"));
```